# CSSLayout File not found

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, ios10

I am using `cocoapods` in react native . 
My pod file contains:

```
target 'Final' do
   use_frameworks!

  pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
  'Core',
  'RCTActionSheet',
  'RCTGeolocation',
  'RCTImage',
  'RCTLinkingIOS',
  'RCTNetwork',
  'RCTSettings',
  'RCTText',
  'RCTVibration',
  'RCTWebSocket',
  'ART'
  ]
end
```

I executed my application its show error:

[image]

Could any one helps to solve this.